# I render multiple props in one component instead of multiple props in multiple component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, render

I try to print a row of cards while looping through a state array that contains API responses.

```
  renderItems(){
    return (
      <div>
      {this.state.apiArr.map( (apiDetails, k) =>(
        <SimpleMediaCard key={k} details={apiDetails}></SimpleMediaCard>))}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

and I render it later this way:

```
render() {
    return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
        {this.renderItems()}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

But the problem is that this way I dont render X cards in rows like I want but instead I render only one card, and I see the card's props changing as the mapping is being processed.

I was sure that with a valid unique key, react would be sure to render another component instead of re-rendering the previous one with different props.

Comment: It's not clear what the data in `this.state.apiArr` contains.  What are the values for each `k` in your callback?  (It looks like you may want `(k, apiDetails)` instead of `(apiDetails, k)`, but it's hard to tell with the information given.)

Comment: Is `Grid` supposed to control where things are place?  You only have one `Grid item`.

Comment: This is how I populate my state array: `this.setState( prevState => ({ apiArr: [...prevState, response] }))` right after I get a response from the API. So in the end I have an array of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **UXDart** I managed to fix this. As he mentioned the problem was coming from my state array. I used to build it like this:

```
this.setState( prevState => ({ apiArr: [...prevState, response] }))
```

But this was actually building an array of size 1 with all of my responses in the same array element. All I to do is change to:

```
this.setState( prevState => ({
        apiArr: this.state.apiArr.concat(response)
      }))
```

And it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `Grid` works, but I assume that `item` should be inside the `map`:

```
renderItems(){
    return (
      <div>
      {
       this.state.apiArr.map((apiDetails, k) => (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
             <SimpleMediaCard key={k} details={apiDetails}></SimpleMediaCard>
          </Grid>
       ))
      }
      </div>
    )
}
```

and remove the `<Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>` in your general `render()`.

Comment: so basically the `item` should be inside the `map`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did the changes but it did not correct the main problem

Comment: I think you found where is the problem... I indeed have only one item in my array... I have to change how I populate my state array